# OpenSSL config cuases error in node js crypto. How should the config be updated?

Tags: nodejs, openssl

This was originally posted to the nodejs Github issues page, but it appears that it is an issue with Ubuntu 22.04, so I'm re-posting it here hoping to get further advice. The original thread on Github is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43132.

Whenever trying to sign data using nodejs's crypto module, I get an error that OpenSSL cannot load a shared library. If I set the `OPENSSL_CONF` variable to `/dev/null` before starting node then I am able to sign data without an issue. This indicates that the problem is likely to be in the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` config file; however, I'm at a loss on how to track it down further. What can I do to determine what part of the config is failing? If there is a missing/broken engine, how can I provide a working copy?

**Steps to Reproduce**

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded from a prior version (21.10 probably but I'm not certain). I originally ran into this issue while using a verison of node installed using nvm, but I can also reproduce it using the `nodejs` package installed by apt.

Start `node` and then run this code (NOTE: this key was generated for this example):

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
sign.update("TEST INPUT")
sign.sign(`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`)
```

You get the following error:

```
Uncaught:
Error: error:25066067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could not load the shared library
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:103:29) {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0E076071:configuration file routines:module_run:unknown module name',
    'error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:module_load_dso:error loading dso',
    'error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library'
  ],
  library: 'DSO support routines',
  function: 'dlfcn_load',
  reason: 'could not load the shared library',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_DSO_COULD_NOT_LOAD_THE_SHARED_LIBRARY'
}
```

Signing data outside of nodejs works just fine (junk.pem contains the same key as above):

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign junk.pem junk.pem  | openssl base64
L5ujucYKKzi+ajZi4vVkJNIpoznMLbzZOdgYtS9Y6qrwBlbt9VTpNpzUM3IeWtDe
2gDk563T3qL+1TeLwcbUHiCWeUrCBUdsQofnrAf5pJq9PW4zaWEHjre3g9Gcnqu6
jaWX7K/g1s9RRM0Kif10a3gAzV6Ij3Bw/NsXMouupBd8hUZrqaxwXtcv3pKAtKIS
aIXP34FXtB5qdsAC9kDNH0Sk9hBlhs33eCxhBIOP4xq4IpLWct0aGGDYD8OB1LTC
6JybDir2QqlZ/qmNuesaI7EmW1Pi90MGeTdSG/9nhBTCE0Q0JttNxOfWkSusJADE
N/rBdOR3Fp0PS6FB7hWNzQ==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in latest nodejs versions.
I encountered this issue with node v16.15.0 after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04. Issue resolved after upgrading node to v16.16.0

Related release notes: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/july-2022-security-releases/#dll-hijacking-on-windows-high-cve-2022-32223

Github discussion: https://github.com/nodejs/node/discussions/43184

Answer (score 13):

The [workaround provided by Zoho](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/cant-install-zoho-workdrive-app-in-ubuntu-22-04) works for me:

> Hence, we suggest you to comment out the lines `providers = provider_sect` in the file `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and restart application once.

That is, find the `openssl_init` section and change it to:

```
[openssl_init]
#providers = provider_sect
```

OpenSSL states that if no provider is explicitly configured, the default is loaded, so removing the explicit provider (apparently part of `fipsinstall`) should be safe.

Comment: This fixed my problem when generating jwt tokens via the https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-jwks library in node, using Pop OS 22.04 (Ubuntu under the hood)